# zepto function not what's selector.item

Tags: javascript, zepto

When I read source code of zepto, I found there is a something that I can't understand.

For example:
'not' function: what's selector.item?
There is someone said 
IsFunction (selector.item) is to exclude the selector for the array.
But how to exclude? And why exclude?

This is source code:

```
else {
    var excludes = typeof selector == 'string' ? this.filter(selector) :
        (likeArray(selector) && isFunction(selector.item)) ? slice.call(selector) : $(selector)

    this.forEach(function(el){
        if (excludes.indexOf(el) < 0) nodes.push(el)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also read the zepto source code recently, I had found the answer from MDN, It's to exclude HTMLCollection. Because HTMLCollection is array like, and has the method `item`. Here is document [HTMLCollection.item](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection/item)

Comment: Include a link to the answer is not a good one. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).